# Will the use of count(distinct depositor.account_number) make a difference here

Tags: sql, database

Given Database Schema:
[The primary key for the tables is mentioned in bold)
account(**account_no** , branch_name,balance)
depositor(customer_name,account_number)  {No key was stated here}
customer(**customer_name**,customer_street,customer_city)

The question required to write the SQL query for - Find average balance for each customer who lives in Harrison and has atleast 3 accounts.

I wrote the following SQL query:

```
select depositor.customer_name,avg(balance)
from depositor,account,customer
where depositor.account_number=account.account_number and
          depositor.customer_name=customer.customer_name  and
          customer_city='Harrison'
group by depositor.customer_name
having count(depositor.account_number) >=3
```

My textbook mentions of the query as:

```
select depositor.customer_name,avg(balance)
from depositor,account,customer
where depositor.account_number=account.account_number and
          depositor.customer_name=customer.customer_name  and
          customer_city='Harrison'
group by depositor.customer_name
having count( distinct depositor.account_number) >=3
```

Would placing distinct here lead to a change in result ?
  According to my analysis, The cross-product of the resultant relation (depositor*account*customer) will have the candidate key as 
 **customer_name account_number** so distinct would not add any value here.

Comment: If your textbook uses commas in the `FROM` clause, I would get another text book.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  My apologies but it does. It is Database System Concepts by Silberschatz,Korth and Sudarshan.

Comment: Commas mean full outer join which is why you have `WHERE` conditions to make it work like an INNER join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your comment deserves to be framed :-) I would also add "...and ask the instructor who recommended that textbook for your money back."

Comment: @AmishaBansal . . . The book is on its Sixth Edition.  It is admirable that it is popular.  It is pathetic that the authors have not updated the SQL for the modern world.  It makes me wonder what other inaccuracies would be in the book.  Needless to say, I would not choose such a book for any classes that I teach.

Comment: Give two customers the same name and see if it makes a difference. I think you'll find it does.

Comment: @shawnt00  As mentioned the question mentions customer_name as the primary key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `depositor` table stores unique combinations of `customer_name` and `account_number`, meaning that adding DISTINCT in the count should not make a difference.

But if the table was a fact table which had repeating instances of the same `account_number` you wouldn't want to count the same account number twice and in that case, it would have made a difference.

But in your case, it should not make a difference since the other two tables also seem to contain unique combinations of their respective fields.

Comment: Thanks.You mean to say if the tuple replicaion was allowed "distinct" would have made a difference?

Comment: Yes. Imagine for a given customer with a total of three entries for `account_number` looked like `111`, `333`, `111`. Using `COUNT()` would give you 3 accounts but using `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would give only 2 accounts. So with `COUNT(DISTINCT)` it would get filtered out. This is only when you had repeating instances of `account_number`.

Comment: But it would have been the case only when depositor table was allowed to have the duplicate tuples. A relational table, we assume, to have distinct tuples,so it should not make a difference here?

Comment: In your case, as I mentioned in the post, using `DISTINCT` should not make a difference since there are no duplicate tuples in the table. Best if you can verify that there are no duplicates to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since the depositor table doesn't have a primary key constraint it would be possible to duplicate a name-account pairing. Your textbook likely hasn't discussed composite keys so this was possibly intended as a way to catch that scenario. Unfortunately the extra row(s) would still throw off the average   calculation though getting the three accounts qualification correct.